# Sorting a sub-array in an array according to some condition - Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

If `X = [['orange','apple','red'],['$40','red','apple','30','orange'],['cool','apple'], ['pool','fun','e']...]`, would it be possible to rearrange the sub-arrays according to some condition we specify?

As we see, for this array, each sub-array is different size. So, if we say that we want to see "apple" appear in each sub-array first, then "apple" should appear first in each sub-array. Or if that is not possible, then "orange" should come first, and if that is not possible, then...

So what I mean is, `X` should appear as `X = [['apple','orange','red'],['apple','$40','red','30','orange'],['apple','cool'], ['pool','fun','e']...]` after rearranging the array. How can one do this? I tried `X.sort` but that sorts it differently. I tried searching Google and came up with nothing useful.

If someone could point me in the right direction of some example or tutorial, that would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Showing your `X.sort` would be very helpful for those trying to assist you in this.

Comment: Why 'orange' moved to the last position in first subarray?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That was actually a mistake. 'Orange' should come second.

Comment: @user65422 is it possible that a sub list can have multiple 'apple' or 'orange' in it?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No. Just one of each.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each item(say `item`) of X and then loop over a list that contains `['apple', 'oranges', ...]` etc, so for each item(say `x`) in this list call `list.remove` on `item` and if it works without any error then simply insert it back at 0th index and break out of the inner loop otherwise continue with 'orange' and rest of the items in the inner loop.

```
X = [['orange','apple','red'],
     ['$40','red','apple','30','orange'],
     ['cool','apple'], ['pool','fun','e']]

items = ['apple', 'orange']

for item in X:
    for x in items:
        try:
            item.remove(x)
            item.insert(0, x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            break

print X
```

**Output:**

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'red'],
 ['apple', 'red', '$40', '30', 'orange'],
 ['apple', 'cool'],
 ['pool', 'fun', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_preference_getter(items):
    prefs  = {item:i for i,item in enumerate(items)}
    bad_val = len(prefs)
    return lambda x: prefs.get(x, bad_val), bad_val

def my_sort(lst, pref_fn, bad_val):
    pref, item = min((pref_fn(item), item) for item in lst)
    if pref == bad_val:
        # no preferred value found
        return lst
    else:
        index = lst.index(item)
        return [item] + lst[:index] + lst[index + 1:]
```

then

```
pref_fn, bad_val = make_preference_getter(["apple", "orange", "red"])

data = [
    ['orange','apple','red'],
    ['$40','red','apple','30','orange'],
    ['cool','apple'],
    ['pool','fun','orange']
]

data = [my_sort(sublst, pref_fn, bad_val) for sublst in data]
```

produces

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'red'],
 ['apple', '$40', 'red', '30', 'orange'],
 ['apple', 'cool'],
 ['orange', 'pool', 'fun']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` parameter to `sorted()` to change the sorting behavior. Empty strings sort before anything else so we convert `'apple'` into an empty string when the sort function does it's comparisons.

```py
X2 = [sorted(sa, key=lambda w:'' if w == 'apple' else w) for sa in X]
```

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but doesn't " x:'' " give some error?

Comment: No. It's the syntax for a lambda function. I suppose I should have used a variable other than `x` to avoid confusion with `X`.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify your own function for comparing the elements you want to sort. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting